# Yii2 : Setting Access Control matchcallback

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I just want to know if I can do this so I dont have to repeat the same code over and over

```
[
  'allow' => true,
  'actions' => ['index', 'update', 'view', 'logout'],
  'roles' => ['@'],
  'matchCallback' => function(){
                        return (Yii::$app->user->identity->team_id == '47' && Yii::$app->user->identity->team_id == '62'
                        && Yii::$app->user->identity->team_id == '63' && Yii::$app->user->identity->team_id == '64'
                        && Yii::$app->user->identity->team_id == '65' && Yii::$app->user->identity->team_id == '66' && Yii::$app->user->identity->role_id == '1');
                    }
                ],
```

Or something similar to that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't understand why you are using && instead of ||. Is it a typo?
Now for answering the question, I think it will be better for example to create a function for that purpose in the Model representing your identity like below: (I am sure you will need it later somewhere else)

```
public function belongsToGroup()
{
    if( $this->team_id == '47' 
        || $this->team_id == '62' 
        ... 
        && $this->role_id == '1' ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And then just call your function in the authorisation control:

```
[
 'allow' => true,
 'actions' => ['index', 'update', 'view', 'logout'],
 'roles' => ['@'],
 'matchCallback' => function($rule, $action){
                    return Yii::$app->user->identity->belongsToGroup();
                   }
],
```

Comment: Thanks :) and about the && and || thing, it's my mistake :D thank you very much